# Calling a method on an uninitialized object (null pointer)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization, null-pointer

1. What is the normal behavior in Objective-C if you call a method on an object (pointer) that is nil (maybe because someone forgot to initialize it)? Shouldn't it generate some kind of an error (segmentation fault, null pointer exception...)?
2. If this is normal behavior, is there a way of changing this behavior (by configuring the compiler) so that the program raises some kind of error / exception at runtime?

To make it more clear what I am talking about, here's an example.

Having this class:

```
@interface Person : NSObject {

    NSString *name;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;

- (void)sayHi;

@end
```

with this implementation:

```
@implementation Person

@synthesize name;

- (void)dealloc {
    [name release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)sayHi {
    NSLog(@"Hello");
    NSLog(@"My name is %@.", name);
}

@end
```

Somewhere in the program I do this:

```
Person *person = nil;
//person = [[Person alloc] init]; // let's say I comment this line
person.name = @"Mike";            // shouldn't I get an error here?
[person sayHi];                   // and here
[person release];                 // and here
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

A message sent to a `nil` object is perfectly acceptable in Objective-C, it's treated as a no-op. There is no way to flag it as an error because it's not an error, in fact it can be a very useful feature of the language.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH4-SW22):

> **Sending Messages to nil**
>
> In Objective-C, it is valid to send a
>   message to nil—it simply has no effect
>   at runtime. There are several patterns
>   in Cocoa that take advantage of this
>   fact. The value returned from a
>   message to nil may also be valid:
>
> - If the method returns an object, then a message sent to `nil` returns
>     `0` (`nil`), for example:
>
>   `Person *motherInLaw = [[aPerson spouse] mother];`
>
>   If `aPerson`’s `spouse` is `nil`,
>     then `mother` is sent to `nil` and the
>     method returns `nil`.
> - If the method returns any pointer type, any integer scalar of size less
>     than or equal to `sizeof(void*)`, a
>     `float`, a `double`, a `long double`,
>     or a `long long`, then a message sent
>     to `nil` returns `0`.
> - If the method returns a `struct`, as defined by the Mac OS X ABI
>     Function Call Guide to be returned in
>     registers, then a message sent to
>     `nil` returns `0.0` for every field in
>     the data structure. Other `struct`
>     data types will not be filled with
>     zeros.
> - If the method returns anything other than the aforementioned value
>     types the return value of a message
>     sent to nil is undefined.

Comment: And I'm not aware of any way to change this behaviour. It's a fundamental part of programming with Objective-C/Cocoa. You will learn to love it.

Answer (score 13):

From [Greg Parker](https://twitter.com/gparker)'s [site](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2012/2/29/objc_explain_return_value_of_message_to_nil.html):

If running LLVM Compiler 3.0 (Xcode 4.2) or later

```
Messages to nil with return type | return
Integers up to 64 bits           | 0
Floating-point up to long double | 0.0
Pointers                         | nil
Structs                          | {0}
Any _Complex type                | {0, 0}
```

Answer (score 6):

One thing you should be clear on is that in Objective-C, you don't *call a method on* an object, you *send a message to* an object.  The runtime will find the method and call it.

Since the first versions of Objective-C, a message to nil has always been a safe no-op that returns nil.  There's a lot of code that depends on this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happened. When you send a message to nil it means that there is no receiver
and the message fly away. `objc_msgSend` method is used from `Runtime` library. `Message dispatch` mechanism is used that is why `Objective-C` is different and there are a lot of advantages are based on this principle. It will not throws any errors as `Java` or `Swift` do