# How to display a view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm new to iOS development.

I have a ViewController `ViewController` with a button. When the user presses that button, I want to switch the view to `RegisterViewController`.

`ViewController.m` contains following code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "RegisterViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize registerViewButton;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)registerViewButtonClick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"registerViewButtonClick called");

    RegisterViewController* controller = [[RegisterViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];    
}

@end
```

According the debug output, method registerViewButtonClick is actually called, when I press the button.

But the view represented by RegisterViewController doesn't appear.

The code of the application is available [here](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s35/sh/1936aac1-482f-489f-a392-ac0f7754500a/96e7c347ca54556335523bb7545081cc).

What do I need to change in order for the RegisterViewController's view to become visible, when the button is pressed?

Comment: Do you actually have a navigation controller? In other words: Is `self.navigationController` not `nil`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran your code and found that there is no navigation controller implemented in your code but you are trying to push the registerViewController. Try to present the viewcontroller like below:

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

instead of

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

The `pushViewController` works only when there is a UINavigationController. As per the documentation, The UINavigationController class implements a specialized view controller that manages the navigation of hierarchical content. Since, there is no UINavigationController in your code (`self.navigationController` is `nil` in this case), nothing happens when you try to push the viewController.

UINavigationController also comes handy when you want to maintain a stack of viewControllers wherein you can push or pop as per the need. This also gives you 'Back' button automatically. If your need is just to present a viewcontroller, then `presentViewController:` can be the right option.

Comment: If you feel generous you could edit your answer and tell the OP why messages sent to `nil` don't do anything.

Comment: @GenieWanted Many thanks for your answer. Forgive me a dumb question, but why does a call to a `nil` object not cause a `NullReferenceExeption` or something similar (like it would in Java and C#) ?

Comment: This is infact an interesting question.. This is greatly explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696891/calling-a-method-on-an-unitialized-object-null-pointer ... It's all about how Objective C looks at it.

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to present then no need of UINavigationalController.
- But for pushing UINavigationalController is must .
- In Storyboard, you have to add one UINavigationalController.

[image]

- In Button Actions initialise the VC correctly with nib Name.

> ```
>  RegisterViewController* controller = [[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];
>     [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to initialize the UIViewController with the nib name..

like this

`RegisterViewController* controller = [[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

```
RegisterViewController *news=[[RegisterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegisterViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:news animated:YES];
[news release];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards then you need to get your view controller from the storyboard like

```
RegisterViewController *viewController = (RegisterViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vc-identifier"];
```

Replace `vc-identifier` with whatever you have given as the identifier in storyboards and replace `MainStoryboard` with the name of your storybaord.

then pass it into your navigation controller like you are already doing, that is as long as your navigation controller isn't `nil`

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Just been told that you aren't using storyboards, I was unable to download your link because of my location so I gave a solution with storyboards. My recommendation would be to move to using storyboards.

**Will leave this here as it may help others who are having the same problem but are using storyboards**