# EXC_BAD_ACCESS error at viewwillappear using scrollToRowAtIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, tableview, exc-bad-access, viewwillappear

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when using scrollToRowAtIndexPath in the viewWillAppear method. I searched for solutions and saw some old posts recommending to set delegate and table to nil (see code below), however when I set that I simply dont get anything loaded in my tableview.
I should say that this is part of a chat application where I want to show the last message entered first. Many thanks for any assistance with this.
Here's my viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.table reloadData];
    int lastRowNumber = [self.table numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
    NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
    //self.table.delegate = nil;
    //self.table = nil;
    [self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];

}
```

I should add that this code seems to work fine in other parts of my program, the only time I get the error is in the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2696909/3324388

Comment: Try setting animated to NO.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong from your code. I created a demo project and copied your code to it. it works perfectly. Maybe something wrong with your data source.

Answer (score 2):

`viewWillAppear:` is too early to do any animation on view. Per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillAppear:):

> This method is called before the view controller's view is about to
>   be added to a view hierarchy and before any animations are configured
>   for showing the view. You can override this method to perform custom
>   tasks associated with displaying the view. For example, you might use
>   this method to change the orientation or style of the status bar to
>   coordinate with the orientation or style of the view being presented.
>   If you override this method, you must call super at some point in your
>   implementation.

So, you cannot add animations when even the view hierarchy is not set completely.

Answer (score 0):

It may help you

```
NSIndexPath * lastIndex =[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:yourContenetArray.count-1 inSection:0];

[self.yourTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndex atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I still get the same EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. Actually this code does work in other parts of my program, the error only occurs in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

```
Write your code in viewDidAppear method.As your table view is loaded 
then after you should call the method scrollToRowAtIndexPath . Then 
your animation will be performed.And if you want to use in 
viewWillAppear , then You can try to reload your tableView and then
write code for scrollToRowAtIndexPath
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, however this does not clear the error. I get the same error whether I am using the ViewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear.

Comment: hi , have you tried your code after reloading the tableview. ?

Comment: Yes I put a reload into the ViewDidAppear before the code that causes the error, but still get the error. Or are you suggesting to put it elsewhere?

Comment: Use reload tableview after that write your code for scrolToRowAtIndexPath in viewWillAppear only , or Else write the same thing in viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use the `viewDidLoad` method for scrolling, and if your array count is 0 (empty array) it will throw an error. It is not possible to scroll to cell at index `-1`.