# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in CJSONDeserializer.m setData method

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, xcode

I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the latest version of CJSONDeserializer.m at the setData method. i.e. in here

```
- (BOOL)_setData:(NSData *)inData error:(NSError **)outError;
```

See screenshot:

[image: setData]

It started happening when I added an entry under NSExceptionDomains (as mentioned here: [NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed on iOS 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30739473/nsurlsession-nsurlconnection-http-load-failed-on-ios-9/30836686#30836686) )

Any suggestions how to proceed?

Comment: do you check to see that you're getting an error? are you actually receiving data?

Comment: No, I'm not receiving any data. Does Obj-C raise an exception when calling a method on nil?

Comment: Obj-c will not crash if you call a method of an object that is nil ([theData getLenght];  would just return nil but here you accessing a property of an object that is nil that would cause an error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696891/calling-a-method-on-an-unitialized-object-null-pointer